# How to show input value next to it ? Python

Tags: django, python-2.7, jinja2

So I'm sending an item to my html page and put a value off this item in an input.
What i want is when i change the input, i want to dynamically print the new value next to the input.

Something like that :

> `<input type='text' value="{{item.qty}}"/>
>   {{myNewInputValue}}`

I know how to do this with angular but don't know if it's possible with Python

Thanks

Comment: I believe that this can't be achieved with Python but can be done with javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately you can't do this directly with Django. You'll have to set up an AJAX handler (probably on keypress) in order to do this.

Comment: Ok thanks at leat i know i need to find another way :)